# div with same margin top and bottom (no %)

Tags: html, css, border, margin, padding

all I want is to have a small black line on the left of the screen with borders top and bottom 30px.

It's pretty much this but if I use the % I won't have those 30 px on the top and bottom.

```
#border-right {
    right:0; 
    width: 71px; 
    height: 94%; 
    top: 3%; 
    bottom: 3%; 
    position:fixed; 
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    border-left:2px solid black;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Here's where I'm stuck now — https://jsfiddle.net/9o3t5u2d/

Thanks!
F.

Comment: The question is still not clear. Are you talking about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9o3t5u2d/1/)? Or [that](https://jsfiddle.net/9o3t5u2d/2/)?

Comment: yes @notulysses but I want the margin top and bottom to be 30px and not % linked with the page height.

EDIT: that that works perfectly! I didn't know about the calc option, thanks.

Comment: So you want a 2px line to the right edge of the screen, with 3% white space at the top and bottom? Why do you have a 71px width? Or do you want 30px think lines on top and bottom of the 2px solid line? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set the top and bottom offsets to 30px, no math required.

I am not sure why you need a width and background color, but you can add it as needed.

```css
#border-right {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  width: 30px; /* Not sure if you need this... */
  background: rgba(125, 125, 125, .5); /* Not sure if you need this... */
}
```

```html
<div id="border-right"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want borders on top and bottom?

Also, Do you mean right? not left?

```
#border-right-top
{         
right:0; 
width: 70px; 
height: 30px; 
bottom: 0px;     
position:fixed; 
background:rgba(255,255,255,.9);
border-left:2px solid black;
z-index:1;
}
```